# Elkies points in the plane of a triangle $ABC$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Noam Elkies proved that if $x,y,z$ are positive numbers, then there is a unique point $P$ inside $ABC$ such that the inradii $r_a,r_b,r_c$ of the triangles $BPC, CPA, APB,$ respectively, satisfy

$$ r_a : r_b : r_c = x : y : z.$$

Can someone find barycentric coordinates for Elkies points?

Elkies's proof appears in *Math. Mag.* **60** (1987), 117. I'd especially like to have such coordinates when $x : y : z$ are barycentric coordinates of a well-known point, such as the incenter, centroid, circumcenter,  Fermat point, or a Hofstadter point.

Comment: So I'm guessing you would like to get the barycentric coordinates of $P$ in terms of $r_a:r_b:r_c$ and the side lengths $a,b,c?$

Comment: Aaron, yes, or equivalently, in terms of $r_a, r_b, r_c$ and the angles $A, B, C$, or all nine:  $r_a, r_b, r_c, a, b, c, A, B, C$.